# Max of two values, where one cannot be equal to a predefined value

Tags: c++, max

I'm looking for a nice readable way to write this(a and b are input):

```
int value = 50;
if(a == value) return b;
if(b == value) return a;
return max(a,b);
```

This is far to long. I have come up with this, but this is not clear enough:

```
return (a==value)?b:((b==value)?a:max(a,b))
```

is there a way to achieve this with only the max define?

Comment: What's the point in `value` in your first example?

Comment: What's "unreadable" about your first piece of code?

Comment: What if `a==b==value` ? Because otherwise it might be written as `int R = max(a,b); if (R==value) R=min(a,b);`

Comment: @MSalters that would also work, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code should be easy to read and understand.  Your first code, that you said is far too long, is very clear, and three lines are not an unreasonable amount of code for C or C++.

If you will do this often, package it up in a function and just call the function.  If the forbidden number can change, make it an argument to the function.

Note that the ternary expression is essentially identical to the code using `if` statements.  They will likely compile to identical code.

Comment: i guess i'll put this in a function.